# How to setup Module Specific ACL Resource?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

Zend's Acl allows the resource to be created in controller only

But, the controllers might be on any module not just only the default module. So, I read some article off the internet, I found one and tried this:

```
$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin"));
$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:page"), "admin");
$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:posts"), "admin");
```

But, still, when i browse to the respective pages, I get errors regarding resouce `page` not found, or `posts` not found.

How to setup Module Specific ACL Resource?

### Update:

```
$acl -> addrole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
    -> addrole(new Zend_Acl_ROle('admin'), 'admin');

$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("page")); //controller with same name in admin module exists

$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin"));
$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:page"), "admin");
$acl -> addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:posts"), "admin");

$acl -> deny(null, null);
$acl -> allow('user', 'page', 'view');
$acl -> allow('admin', null);
```

Comment: The code submitted here is correct. The error you get is coming from somewhere else; wherever it is you check if the current role can access the `page` resource, perhaps (should check `admin:page` instead). More likely your error is from where you add permissions (`allow` or `deny`) to roles.

Comment: @adlawson, I am afraid that's not the case of role, because there are only two types of error, guest and admin and admin is allowed to everything, using `$acl -> allow("admin", null);`

Comment: In that case, you need to post more code. The error is not in the above snippet.

Comment: @adlawson, Ok, check out the update section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the code you posted was some sort of pseudo code, as it wasn't valid. Still, this answer should work perfectly fine as is.

```
$acl->addrole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
    ->addrole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'guest');

$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("page"));
$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin"));
$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:page"), "admin");
$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("admin:posts"), "admin");

$acl->deny();
$acl->allow('guest', 'page', 'view');
$acl->allow('admin');

// Lets run some quick tests...
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('guest', 'page', 'view')); // true
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('guest', 'page', 'edit')); // false
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('guest', 'admin:page', 'view')); // false

var_dump($acl->isAllowed('admin', 'page', 'view')); // true
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('admin', 'page', 'edit')); // false
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('admin', 'admin:page', 'view')); // true
```

Comment: Why when I comment line `$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource("page"));` and browse to `/admin/page`, it says resouce `page` cannot be found. Willn't `admin:page` define page as a resource inside admin.

Comment: No. The resource name used is the **exact** name you give it. So for `admin:page` you have to use it exactly like that. Calling your child resource `admin:page` is a naming convention. You could have called it `my_ToTaLlY::unique-resourceName` if you wanted, but you have to use it exacly like that from then on.

Comment: Then, how will I be able to differentiate the page resource of the default modudle and the page resource of admin module.

Comment: You are already half way there. You have `admin:page`. Now you need `default:page`. That's it. Two completely different resource names.

Comment: In your example, which resource will `$acl->allow('guest', 'page', 'view');` address. I tried your default: and admin: way and allowed guest, to the index controller of admin module's index controller, `$acl -> allowed('guest', 'admin:index');` but still guest can browse /admin page

Comment: `$acl->allow('guest', 'page', 'view');` won't work at all, unless you define a resource called **page**. It shouldn't. It won't. It can't. **It's not magic**.

Comment: I tried your default: and admin: way and allowed guest, to the index controller of admin module's index controller, $acl -> allowed('guest', 'admin:index'); and still I can't browse it, Why? (i am sorry, the last comment was reversed)

Comment: @mrN let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2716/discussion-between-adlawson-and-mrn)

Comment: +1, and accept, thats the least I can do for helping me out, thank you so much